# Solving an equation involving the trace of a field

Tags: finite-fields, trace, exponential-sum

Let $F$ be a finite field of order $q$ where $q=2^{n}$ and fix $l\in F\setminus{0}$ with $Tr(l)=0$. I want to determine the number of $a$ such that 
$$Tr(la)=Tr(la^{-1})=1,$$

where $Tr$ denotes the trace of a field element.

Could anyone give any hints on how to start?

Many thanks.

Comment: Looks like this number can be given in terms of a Kloosterman sum. Meaning that the answer will depend on the choice of $\ell$, and will cover a range of values with roughly known distribution.

Comment: @ Jyrki In particular, I just want to show that for each $l\in F\setminus 0$ there are at least $3$ such values of $a$ (provided that $q\geq 8$). Could you give me anymore details on the method you mentioned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\chi:\Bbb{F}_q\to\{\pm1\}$ be the canonical additive character
$$
\chi(x)=(-1)^{tr(x)}.
$$
Fix an element $\ell\in\Bbb{F}_q^*$.
Consider the function $f(x)=(1-\chi(\ell x))(1-\chi(\ell x^{-1}))$. It follows that for $a\in\Bbb{F}_q^*$ we have $f(a)=4$, if $tr(\ell a)=1=tr(\ell a^{-1})$ and $f(a)=0$ otherwise.

Let $N(\ell)$ be the number of elements $a$ with the prescribed properties. The above consideration shows that
$$
\begin{aligned}
4N(\ell)&=\sum_{x\in\Bbb{F}_q^*}(1-\chi(\ell x))(1-\chi(\ell x^{-1}))\\
&=\sum_{x\in\Bbb{F}_q^*}\left(1-\chi(\ell x)-\chi(\ell x^{-1})+\chi(\ell x+\ell x^{-1})\right).
\end{aligned}
$$
Here, trivially
$$
\sum_{x\in\Bbb{F}_q^*}1=q-1
$$
and by the elementary properties of character sums
$$
\sum_{x\in\Bbb{F}_q^*}\chi(\ell x)=-1=\sum_{x\in\Bbb{F}_q^*}\chi(\ell x^{-1}).
$$
The last sum on the other hand is not trivial. But it is a so called [Kloosterman sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kloosterman_sum). They are known to be bounded from above as follows
$$
\left\vert\sum_{x\in\Bbb{F}_q^*}\chi(\ell x+\ell x^{-1})\right\vert \le 2\sqrt q.
$$
The bound is of the same type as the Weil bounds on multiplicative character sums and the Carlitz-Uchiyama bound on additive character sums. It is mentioned (and IIRC also proven) in Lidl & Niederreiter as well as many other texts. Because we are in characteristic two we can also get this bound from the Hasse-Weil bound on the number of points on an elliptic curve over a finite field. Namely, it is easy to show that the number of $\Bbb{F}_q$-rational points on the curve
$$
y^2+xy=\ell x^3+\ell x
$$
is equal to $q+1+\sum_{x\in\Bbb{F}_q^*}\chi(\ell x+\ell x^{-1})$.

Anyway, we can deduce that
$$
|4N(\ell)-(q+1)|\le 2\sqrt q,
$$
and consequently
$$
N(\ell)\ge\frac{q+1-2\sqrt q}4.
$$
So if $q\ge16$ we deduce that $N(\ell)\ge 9/4$. As $N(\ell)$ is obviously an integer, you get the desired $N(\ell)\ge3$. I suggest that you use brute force to see what happens, when $q=8$.

Comment: Many thanks! I don't quite know which elementary properties of character sums we are using to get the $-1$ for the two sums. Could you provide me some explaining or some reference for this? Also, according to the Wikipedia page a Kloosterman sum is an exponential sum; I don't seem to understand how the sum mentioned in your answer is a Kloosterman sum.

Comment: I have managed to figure out why the sum is a Kloosterman sum. So now I would just like to know which elementary properties are being used to get the $-1$'s for the two character sums.

Comment: The character $x\mapsto \chi(\ell x)$ is non-trivial (i.e. not constant $1$). Therefore
$$S=\sum_{x\in\Bbb{F}_q}\chi(\ell x)=0.$$ This is because there exists $y\in\Bbb{F}_q$ such that $\chi(\ell y)=-1$. Therefore
$$S=\sum_{x\in\Bbb{F}_q}(\chi(\ell[x+y])=\sum_x\chi(\ell x)\chi(\ell y)=-S.$$ This is the most basic character sum. What textbooks on character sums have you looked at?

Comment: I understand now - thanks! I didn't have access to relevant textbooks at the time but I did search a lot online for basic properties of character sums but couldn't find anything useful.